# How to convert Reserved check-out to unreserved check-out using CCRC 7.1.2 win version

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

How can I change checkout type from Reserved to Unreserved ?

I am working in Windows environment and I am using CCRC 7.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the [CCRC version tree view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21209312), you should be able to select properties on the checked out version, and see a [reserved checkout](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135939) tick that you can un-tick.

[image: version tree in CCRC]

<sup>(That specific screenshot is just an example, and has no checked out version in it)</sup>

But you must be in the right view, as the right user, ie as the user who checked out that file.

If this is unavailable in 7.1.2, or if you are not the right user in the right view, then report to the IBM technote "[How to convert a reserved checkout or force the uncheckout of a file that was checked out from CCRC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21288605)".
This is done on the CCRC server, where a full ClearCase is installed (ie, `cleartool` is available).

#### TO UNRESERVE A RESERVED CHECKOUT (recommended approach)

> The unreserve command can be performed by an Administrator or Root on the back end storage of the user’s web view. First determine the view in question by executing “`cleartool lsview`” on the server, which will display the web views like this:

```
viewtag      hostname:CC:\ccweb\{USERNAME}\{END USER’S VIEW}\view.stg
```

> An administrator can then convert the previously reserved checkout to unreserved as follows:

```
cleartool unreserve -view hostname:C:\ccweb\{USERNAME}\{END USER’S VIEW}\view.stg C:\ccweb\{USERNAME}\{END USER’S VIEW}\{VOBTAG}\directory\filename

cleartool: Warning: This tool should not be used to access a Web View.  All access to a Web view should be via the Web interface.  Changes in the view's server side state will not be reflected in the client

Changed checkout to unreserved for "`:\ccweb\{USERNAME}\{END USERS VIEW}\{VOBTAG}\directory\filename`" branch "`\main`".
```

---

Comment: I want to change for other user, I do have admin rights but working from CCRC not on ClearCase server.

Comment: @RaG if you want to change for another user, then you need to ask an admin: he/she will have access to the CCRC server, where a full ClearCase on that server, even if the clients are using CCRC.